# Add a file to subversion with special characters like '%' in the filename

Tags: svn, jruby

I want to commit a version of jruby into my svn repository and there are a number of files under the jruby-1.2.0/share/ri/1.8/system/Matrix directory with the special character '%' in the file names.  When I try to check these files into svn I get the following error:

> svn: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: '/!svn/wrk/jruby-1.2.0/share/ri/1.8/system/Matrix/%252f-i.yaml' path not found

The actual file name is '%2f-i.yaml'.  So, it appears that svn is encoding the file name replacing the '%' character with '%25' causing the error message.  Is there something special I need to do with svn so that the '%' character is not encoded?

Comment: works on my setup (windows XP/apache 2.2.11 / svn 1.5.6)
can you provide more details(svn and apache version and your svn add command you issued before)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files under share/ri should be ignored and not committed back to the repository; they are the expanded RI document sources for core libraries and classes.

In other news, JRuby has moved to Git for source control. Check out http://www.jruby.org for details on how to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Why do you need such a filename?

Answer (score 0):

Hm. The first try for a work-around would be to specify the filename as not "`x%x`" but
"`x%25x`", in whatever way your client might let you do that. (Obviously this is going to be much easier from a command-line client running under Unix.)